# Best Deep-DQN implementation that works with (state,action) pairs

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm moderately new to RL(Reinforcement learning) and trying to solve a problem by using a deep Q learning agent (trying a bunch of algorithms) and I don't want to implement my own agent (I would probably do a worse job than anyone writing an RL library).

My problem is that the way I'm able to view my state space is as (state,action) pairs which poses a technical problem more than an algorithmic one.
I've found libraries that allow me to upload my own Neural network as a Q function estimator,
but I haven't been able to find a library that allows me to evaluate
(state,action) -> Q_estimation  or even better [(state,action)_1,...,(state,action)_i] -> action to take according to policy (either greedy or exploratory).
all I've found are libraries that allow me to input "state" and "possible actions" and get Q values or action choice back.
My second problem is that I want to control the horizon - meaning I want to use a finite horizon.

In short, what I'm looking for is :
A RL library that will allow me to use a deep - Q-network agent that accepts (state,action) pairs and approximates the relevant Q value.
Also I would like to control the horizon of the problem.

Does anyone know any solutions, I've spent days searching the internet for an implemented solution

Answer (score 0):

There is some reward "function" `R(s,a)` (or perhaps `R(s')` where `s'` is determined by the state-action pair) that gives the reward necessary for training a deep Q learner in this method. The reason why there aren't really out-of -box solutions is that the reward function is up to your discretion to define based on the specific learning problem and furthermore is dependent on your state transition function `P(s,s',a)` which gives the probability of reaching state `s'` from state `s` given action `a`. This function is also learning problem specific.

Let's assume for simplicity that your reward function is a function only of the state. In this case, you simply need to write a function that scores each reachable state starting from state `s` and given action `a` and weights it by the probability of reaching that state.

```
def get_expected_reward(s,a):
    # sum over all possible next states
    expected value = 0
    for s_next in reachable:
       # here I assume your reward is a function of state
       # and I assume your transition probabilities are stored in a tensor
       expected_reward +=  P[s,s_next,a] * reward(s_next)

    return expected_reward
```

Then, when training:

```
 (states,actions) = next(dataloader) # here I assume a batch size of b
 targets = torch.tensor(len(actions))
 for b in range(len(actions)):
     targets[b] = get_expected_reward(states[b],actions[b])
 
 # forward pass through model
 predicted_rewards = model(states,actions)

 # loss
 loss = loss_function(predicted_rewards,targets)
```

Comment: Hey @DerekG thanks for the fast reply!
I'm not 100% sure I understand your answer, I'm looking for an out of the box Agent implementation for any Q-learning based algorithm which will allow me to use (state,action) features as input and also allow me to plug in my own NN for Q-value estimation.
Similar perhaps to things referenced here: https://mushroomrl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/mushroom_rl.algorithms.value.html#module-mushroom_rl.algorithms.value.dqn
But that allow me to use (state,action) instead of just state and a list of possible actions.

Comment: Ok but see that this library requires information on the environment (namely an MDP) as an input, which is essentially information on the reward function and the transition function for the process. So it's not really "out-of-box" per se because you have to have a fully specified environment.

Comment: Yes, I've defined my environment completely, and the only way it makes sense to define my environment is with using the state and the action as one feature vector, so my issue now is to find an agent that is able to evaluate Q-values (in whatever algorithm) based on a "state-action" vector of features. and not a "state" and a "list of actions".
I'm trying to avoid coding one up myself.
hope this helps clarify my issue.